# multiplying columns using for-loop and pd.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm having trouble creating a new data table that will show annual energy use data. Basically, I'd like to multiply energy by different factors to show annual energy use.
The code is below.

```
#calculate energy amounts

energy_use_by_fuel = pd.DataFrame()
for hhid in energy_data.hhid.unique(): 
    tempdtf = pd.DataFrame({
       'hhid':hhid, 
       'monthly_electricity': energy_data.loc[energy_data.hhid == hhid, 'estimated_kwh_monthly']*3, 
       'monthly_gas': energy_data.loc[energy_data.hhid == hhid, 'monthly_gas_use_kg'] * 4,
       'monthly_charcoal': energy_data.loc[energy_data.hhid == hhid, 
       'monthly_charcoal_use_kg'] * 5})

    #join
    tempdtf = energy_use_by_fuel.append(tempdtf, ignore_index = True)
```

As you can see, I'd like to calculate different energy uses for electricity, gas and charcoal. But when I multiply the data by the numbers, the resulting dataframe `energy_use_by_fuel` is empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit into your question specific data from `energy_data` as well as the output expected from it? That will help others help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The function `df.append()` does return a new object adding a DataFrame, so I think your code is setting wrong variable.

```
#join
energy_use_by_fuel = energy_use_by_fuel.append(tempdtf, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: the code still doesn't work :(. if you think there is an easier way to do this using other pythonic methods, please let me know! I'm open to not using a loop.